# Resolve variables inside a string - JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I have been trying to figure out if what I am trying is possible using JSTL. I am storing the following inside a database table

```
<c:when test="${row.actionType == 'com'}">  
  ${row.actionText}  
</c:when>
```

thus I am storing the following String in a column in a table

```
<assign name="LocationID" expr="'${row.locationId}'"/> 
<submit next="/aotg/dynApp" namelist="UserID AppID LocationID"/>
```

thus the above string for example gets written to `${row.actionText}` and gets resolved. But of course the output in the JSTL is exactly as above without resolving 
the variable `${row.locationId}` inside the String. Can you also somehow resolve the inner variable as well?

Is something like this even possible or do I need to hard code any parameters I might be using inside the JSTL page instead of trying to dynamically read it from 
the table?

Answer (score 2):

The `.jsp` file that contains the JSTL gets compiled into a `.java` file, which is then compiled into a `.class` file and run in the JVM.

Since the `c:when` block was not in the JSP at the time it was compiled it just becomes some output text when the class file is running.

Answer (score 0):

For now I just used a map to solve this. When I have more time I will
see if there is a more elegant way to do this.

```
  Map<String, String> varMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
  varMap.put("#locationId#", locationId.toString());    
  varMap.put("#mainMenu#", mainMenu);   
  varMap.put("#userId#", userId.toString());
  varMap.put("#appId#", appId.toString());    

  command = string;

  for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : varMap.entrySet()) {

      command = command.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
  }
```

Thanks